# Create a dynamic array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am new. It's a basic question i guess. 
Suppose I need to have a dynamic array to store several objects from my Own class,like classA. I ve no idea about how to wrap these classA-objects and put 'em into the array, maybe NSMutableArray. thx alot.

```
@interface classA
{
   int x;
   int y;
}
...
classA *a,*b,*c;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your array with :

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And then add an object with :

```
[myArray addObject:a];
[myArray addObject:b];
```

And so on

You can find it all explained here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks buddy, seems just add the reference of the object directly into the array, is that right? Ok, I'll take a look at the link, thanks again.

Comment: Yes you can add pointers into an array if that's your question

Answer (score 0):

If you need your array to be mutable,

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
[arr addObject:a];
[arr addObject:b];
```

will suffice. Objective-C, like Smalltalk, uses dynamic typing. You can just add the objects.

If you do not need to mutate your array,

```
NSArray *arr = @[a, b];
```